# Writing application log files in azure sdk 2.5 blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I want to write log files that are stored in storage azure blob but I don't really understand how to do this since Azure v2.5. Could someone explain me this please ?

Initially I wanted to create the file  and put in Azure Blob Storage with the framework NLog but from what I've read it doesn't work the same method for Azure v2.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to write out small entities with many properties and want to be able to query them separately I would recommend using Azure Tables rather than blobs. I wrote a C# error log/audit log appender just a few weeks ago that is simple and quick to implement.

I wrote it up in a blog post that was just published [here](http://www.bananagunprogramming.com/?p=244). The post contains a link to my github repository where you can download the 3 classes needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll see if it can bring useful. Just a question : can SCM also be used for cloud services ? Because we have no web application but three cloud services.

Comment: I followed your advice and works perfectly. I will modify to suit my requirements. Thanks !